# Google Spreadsheets information into Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

How can you pull information from a google spreadsheet back into a google form to update the information?

I would like to be able to have the information I have already submitted through a Google Form be pulled up again in the form to update information.  I am aware that I can go and edit the spreadsheet but for my purpose it would be easier to do it through the form.  I have been unable to locate a script that would allow me to do this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You are able to use FormApp in Apps Script to access the form objects for updating.

Below is an example that updates a "Choose from List" object.  If you wanted to update the form after each submission, you could could call the updateList function using the container based trigger "On form submit".

```
function updateList(){
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // get the range of values to update in the form
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var listItemsToAdd = [];
  for(s in data){
    if(logic to define if to add to the form){
      listItemsToAdd.push(data[s][0]);
    }
  }

  // get all the list items in the form
  var list = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
  // grab the first list item in the array of the form's list items
  var item = list[0].asListItem();
  // set the options to the array just created
  item.setChoiceValues(listItemsToAdd);
}
```

Comment: But please don't use `for (s in data)` to loop through an Array.

Comment: @Cyrus Loree: Ok, but I'd like to ask you a question about this; How do I set the values within the for loop with the navigation type? ([like this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice))

Comment: I think this is a different conversation.  If you post a new question, I'll be happy to go into detail.  The short answer is that you pass the page break item instead of the PageNavigationType enumeration.  E.G. var anotherPage = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Another page to go to');  ... item.createChoice('My New Page', anotherPage), item.createChoice('Dogs', FormApp.PageNavigationType.RESTART)
     ]);